# Django LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I want to use django login framework to my first application in django.

This is my django url file

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
...
url(r'^$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name="logout"),
```

In my settings file, I defined these variables:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/conceptos'
```

My django login view doesn't work propertly, always redirect to localhost:8000/index.html. But it shows the login form in localhost/. Why is this happening?